# Transition between sequence and (multi-)set

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-theory, multisets

Do you know any generalization of both sequence and multiset that would allow to get "something in between"?

Something like a tendency to be ordered with the one extreme being unordered and the other being strictly total order.

I have been thinking about probability distributions over permutations, but I was wondering if the concept is already existant - although I did not find anything on the matter...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but could it be the poset of order relations on the set (ordered by inclusion of the pairs)?

Comment: Good point. The lattice formed by the subset relation can be used to structure the permutations. In the strict sequence case, there is only one path with 1 on each edge in the path and 0 on the other edges. In the set case, there is 1/#outgoing weight on each edge. The product of the weights is the probability of this permutation, i.e. for a 3-elemental set, 1/3*1/2*1.

Comment: An ordered multiset.

Comment: But a total order on a multiset does not give the 'soft' transition between sequence and set...